# Windows 10 two sets of virtual desktops

Tags: windows-10

I'd like to have two sets of virtual desktops for each of my monitors. Otherwise I'd like to pin single virtual desktop on one of the monitors. Is it possible?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Split monitor into virtual monitors](https://superuser.com/questions/1055521/split-monitor-into-virtual-monitors)

Comment: Not with what Windows 10 offers out of the box. I know Actual Tools has software that can do this though, but its not free.