# How to show two displays on one monitor?

Tags: multiple-monitors, remote-desktop, display-settings, virtual-desktop, split-window

Would you know how to show multiple displays on one monitor in split view?

I have a Windows 11 desktop and 2 monitors.

I'd like to use most but not all of my first monitor and the entire second monitor to, for instance, RDP into another machine in full screen mode but still have a bit of the first monitor showing me my local machine.

So I have created a virtual display (#3 in below image) and would like my left monitor to show, in a split view, display #3 + display #1 itself (or display #3 + another virtual display if I have to create a second one #4).

Current Windows Display settings:

[image: Display settings]

Desired outcome:

[image: Desired outcomere]

Comment: As an alternative, maybe check the FancyZones power toy or other advanced window layout tools.

Comment: @DanielB I had tried FancyZones, but I often need to go full screen e.g. with RDP, and FancyZones and other apps that just re/size apps don't do what I want it seems. Hence why I thought of adding a virtual display but I want two displays to show on one monitor.

Comment: I've found this solution that requires buying a Virtual Monitor Display Emulator:
https://superuser.com/a/1743677/1709528
.
I'll keep searching for a software-only solution but I'm considering buying one otherwise