# Split monitor into multiple virtual monitors

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, resolution, virtual-desktop

I bought a new monitor (Samsung C49RG9x) as a replacement for my two old monitors. It's not surprising that a lot of people can't handle the insane resolution of 5120x1440, making collaboration/screensharing via Zoom, Skype, .. one real mess. Before sharing my screen, I constantly have to lower my screen resolution if I want people to be able to actually see something on my screen.

Programs like DisplayFusion (as mentioned in this article: [Split monitor into virtual monitors](https://superuser.com/questions/1055521/split-monitor-into-virtual-monitors)) unfortunately do not solve my issue, since they don't "really" split my screen. Skype seems to ignore the partitioning completely.

Is there a way to actually, virtually split the monitor into multiple sections that are separately recognized by programs like skype?

Answer (score 0):

Windows itself does not have this feature, so a third-party product
is indicated. But most of the products advertising screen-splitting
do actually only windows-snapping.

A commercial product that seems to really split the monitor is
[UltraView Desktop Manager](https://www.digitaltigers.com/ultraview-desktop-manager.asp)
(87€).

This is what it advertises :

[image]