# On Windows, Is it possible to split a screen to consider it as 2 different screens

Tags: windows, windows-11

On Windows, I'm trying to split a screen is half. The purpose is to have a small screen on the side of my screen.

The windows sizing functionnalities of windows are good, but I have a part on my screen ONLY used for some "always here" app like a spotify or a whatsapp. The problem is sometimes I cover it with an other windows, I'm alway resizing my windows.

Do you know a soft or an option to do it ?

EDIT :
So, I KNOW snap and powertoys, but this is NOT what I'm looking for.

I will try 2 softs :

- https://www.donationcoder.com/software/mouser/other-windows-apps/desktopcoral, to create a safe zone, it could be ok for me if it's working well. A safe zone will protect my apps from a resize or a snap trigger.
- https://www.displayfusion.com/ seems to propose to divide a screen and add more options for the desks, it could be the answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://superuser.com/questions/1055521/split-monitor-into-virtual-monitors

Comment: Have you tried Microsoft Powertoys? It allows you to split the screen in any way you want.

Comment: Whoops i can see harrymc has already suggested it. Good old harry! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Like this?
Does not split the screen, but reserves space of one app and forces others out of it. https://www.donationcoder.com/software/mouser/other-windows-apps/desktopcoral

Comment: It seems to be a good solution ! I will try the soft. I effectively need a kind of safe zone, so even if it's not a real "split" it could be perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10 and 11 have this [built-in](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/multiple-desktops-in-windows-36f52e38-5b4a-557b-2ff9-e1a60c976434) in the form of virtual desktops, which there are two of by default with the ability to create more. This might be sufficient enough for your usecase that you don't need a third-party solution. Press <kbd>Win</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>→</kbd> to switch to your second desktop (left arrow key to switch back), and <kbd>WinTab</kbd> to see all desktops - this can also be used to drag programs from one to the other. I use this when I need to run something for a few days, like data destruction or recovery, without getting in the way of my more urgent work.

Comment: I copy my answer : Hi, thank you but I already use the functionnality ; However this is not what I'm looking for. Snap is really good when you have 1 screen and a few windows (I personnaly mostly use the powertoy app for managing my screen's canva), In my case I work with 20/30+ windows on 2 or 3 screens, and I need a kind of real "safe zone" for a few softwares.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 11 has the new feature of Snap, described in the article
[Snap your windows](https://geekflare.com/split-screen-on-windows/).

Basically, while your window is active, press
<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> or hover over the Maximum icon in the
title-bar, to show this dialog with six possible layouts:

[image]

Clicking on one rectangle inside any one layout will resize the current
window so it fills the matching part of the screen.

For more information and methods see the article
[How to Split Screen into 2, 3 or 4 Sections on Windows 10/11](https://geekflare.com/split-screen-on-windows/).

---

For more sophisticated layouts, you may use :

- [FancyZones utility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/powertoys/fancyzones)
  which is part of Microsoft's
  [Power Toys](https://github.com/microsoft/PowerToys).
  More information can be found in the article
  [How to use FancyZones, Windows 10’s new tiling window manager](https://www.onmsft.com/how-to/how-to-use-fancyzones-windows-10s-new-tiling-window-manager/).
- [Jgpaiva's GridMove](https://www.dcmembers.com/jgpaiva/)
  might be the most flexible and is
  [open source](https://github.com/jgpaiva/GridMove).

Comment: Hi, thank you but I already use the functionnality ; However this is not what I'm looking for. Snap is really good when you have 1 screen and a few windows (I personnaly mostly use the powertoy app for managing my screen's canva), In my case I work with 20/30+ windows on 2 or 3 screens, and I need a kind of real "safe zone" for a few softwares.

Comment: I added some more options.

Comment: I said I already use power toys, this is not what I'm looking for. I'm looking for a kind of "safe zone", It can be a safe zone or a split screen, or another solution I didn't think about

Comment: If payware is a solution you could use [DisplayFusion](https://www.displayfusion.com/) which does [Monitor Splitting](https://www.displayfusion.com/Features/MonitorSplitting/) for $34 with free trial.

Comment: Thank you, payware is a solution if the soft is really good:) I see they have a free trial