# How can I trick Windows into thinking I have a second monitor?

Tags: windows, video

I used to use two monitors on Windows 11.

When I did a webinar or something, I could use "Presenter View" with PowerPoint. This is where it shows the actual full-screen slide on Monitor A and you get to see your notes and next slide on Monitor B.  I would just share Monitor B to Teams or Zoom or whatever, and I was good.

But I have recently switched to a single, massive, ultra-wide monitor. I have more screen space than before, but only one monitor. This has led to two problems.

1. I can't use Presenter View anymore, because I could only do both on two separate monitors. I can switch to Presenter View, but I want to show the audience one thing, while I see another thing.
2. When I share my current monitor, it's insanely wide, so what's projected kinda sucks -- the viewers get black bars on the sides, with the content smaller in the middle.

How can I "fool" Windows into thinking I have a second monitor, and it's of a normal screen resolution? Part of me thinks I should just plug in an old monitor, but stick it under my desk and not use it. But it would still exist, so I could project to it. But there *has* to be a better way...

I have four inputs on my video card. Is there something I can plug into one of the open ports to make Windows think there's a second monitor there, and can I control the (fake) resolution of it?

Comment: I don't have the rep to add this as a duplicate question.  But does this answer your question? [Split monitor into virtual monitors](https://superuser.com/q/1055521/5253)